# JSON parse error with double quote as unrecognized token

Tags: javascript, json

I've been stuck hours on this supposedly dummy problem.
I am getting data from an hardware device via bluetooth, and after decoding it with :

```
const int8View = new Uint8Array(data)
const decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8')
const toParse = decoder.decode(int8View)
```

I can get a json string that i can print:

```
console.log("should be parsed ", toParse)
-> should be parsed  – "{\"timeStamp\":1580011546,\"startState\":2,\"endState\":3}"
```

but when I use `JSON.parse` on this object I get:

```
SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token ''
```

Answer (score 2):

As often when you take time to clearly explain your problem, you find the solution. As I have found nothing on the matter, I give my answer.

If you copy paste the double quote of the error message in an hidden character view like [this one](https://www.soscisurvey.de/tools/view-chars.php) it will show you that there was an hidden null `\x00` character inside the string.

I removed it with:

```
toParse.toString().trim().replace(/\0/g, '')
```

which solved my problem. 
Hope this helps others.